# Converting string to map in groovy within Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a parameter in Jenkins pipeline that looks like

```
PROPERTY1=1\nPROPERTY2=1
```

The following groovy code seems to work when I tested in [groovy playground](https://groovy-playground.appspot.com/)

```
def original = "PROPERTY1=1\nPROPERTY2=1"

def map = 
    original
    .split('\n')
    .collectEntries { entry ->
        def pair = entry.split('=')
        [(pair.first()):pair.last()]
    }

println(map)    
println("PROPERTY1: " + map.get("PROPERTY1"))
println("PROPERTY2: " + map.get("PROPERTY2"))
```

I'm not even able to split the string on a new line within Jenkins pipeline script

```
node {
    def ext_props = params.get('external_properties') ?: "PROPERTY1=0"
    println("ext_props: " + ext_props)
    println("Split String: " + ext_props.toString().split('\n').join(","))
    // def props = ext_props.split('\n').collectEntries { entry -> def pair = entry.split('='); [(pair.first()):pair.last()] }
    // println(props)
}
```

Output:

```
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
ext_props: PROPERTY1=1\nPROPERTY2=1
[Pipeline] echo (hide)
Split String: PROPERTY1=1\nPROPERTY2=1
[Pipeline] }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I have already tried using `readProperties text: ext_props`

Comment: `.split('\\n')`

Comment: @daggett Can you elaborate why new line character needs to be escaped in Jenkins pipeline script?

Comment: @daggett Actually, this ext_props.split('\\n') didn't work either. Is this the best approach? or Is there a better alternative to convert the parameter to a groovy map?

Answer (score 0):

You are using which version of Jenkins? 
In my environment, I could see proper output as expected.

```
node {
    def ext_props = params.get('external_properties') ?: "PROPERTY1=0\nPROPERTY2=1"
    println("ext_props: " + ext_props)
    println("Split String: " + ext_props.toString().split('\n').join(","))
    // def props = ext_props.split('\n').collectEntries { entry -> def pair = entry.split('='); [(pair.first()):pair.last()] }
    // println(props)
}
```

Output I could see as follows:

```
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
ext_props: PROPERTY1=0
PROPERTY2=1
[Pipeline] echo
Split String: PROPERTY1=0,PROPERTY2=1
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: I'm using Jenkins 2.150.1

Comment: It works when you set `ext_props` directly in the code. Doesn't seem to work when you get the input from a text parameter using `params.get()`